# Testcafe- Upload file getting status 222 with no response and no errors in logs

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to upload a file using testcafe script but its going in infinite loop. I am not getting what's wrong with my code, while all other functionalities except upload are working fine.

```
const click_upload=Selector('input[name="logo"]')
const upload_logo=Selector('input[name="logo"],input[inputtype="file"]')

test
    ('upload file step 3',async t=>{
        await t
        .useRole(somerole)
        .navigateTo('https://xyz.in/')
        .click(click_upload)// Upload button has a css 
        .wait(5000)
        .setFilesToUpload(upload_logo,[
            './_uploads_/image.png'
            ])
        .wait(12000)

    })
```

Its going in **infinite loop** and it's never ending, I even tried to add .debug() and check but no help.
I am getting **status code 222** in api call, and empty response. i.e in upload there is no api call going, I have checked on **console** and I am **not getting any errors**, If I try manually its working.

Comment: The CORS policy is enabled for all origins.

Comment: This is solved, There was issue in s3 config file. Thank you

Comment: Please post your findings as an answer, so it is easily discoverable by other users.

Answer (score 1):

In s3 config there was an issue with CORS policy, it was not enabled for localhost. Also make sure you allowed origin for all, And also one thing you can do is, Not required in every case but configure testcafe to run on HTTPS also.